# LotusScript agent to send mail to multiple recipients from csv file

Tags: excel, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I need LotusScript agent action button to send email to multiple recipients which mail addresses will be read from csv or excel file. I have to send identical mail to couple hundred recipients and it's much easier to send it from excel file than to type or copy each one individually. I've found "Send" method on HCL site and implementation with Static Array example:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
 Dim s As NotesSession
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
 Dim doc As NotesDocument
 Dim rtitem as NotesRichTextItem
 Set s = New NotesSession
 Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
 Set doc = New NotesDocument(db)

 '----------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Build static list of email addresses
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Dim addresses (1 to 3) as String
 addresses(1) = "EMAIL"
 addresses(2) = "EMAIL"
 addresses(3) = "EMAIL"

 '----------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Create and send email message
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------
 doc.Form = "Memo"
 doc.SendTo = addresses
 doc.Subject = "This is the message subject"
 Set rtitem = New NotesRichTextItem(doc, "Body")
 Call rtitem.AddNewLine(1)
 Call rtitem.AppendText("The body of the email message.")
 doc.Send (True)
 Msgbox "Sample email sent"
End Sub
```

This action button should send email to 3 recipients or as many as I manually enter in code but is there a way to send send email to recipients from csv or excel file?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course, there is a way.

To read from a CSV file, you can use the [NotesStream class](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/H_NOTESSTREAM_CLASS.html) to read the data from the file. Or you can use the [Open statement](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/LSAZ_OPEN_STATEMENT.html) and the old BASIC-like [file operations](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/LSAZ_CHAPTER_4_FILE_HANDLING.html) to read data from the file. Either way, of course, you're going to be writing a CSV file parser. You might find some examples of that if you search for them, but really it's not that hard.

To read from an Excel sheet in LotusScript, you're going to need to call the [Excel API classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.application?view=excel-js-preview). Here's one example that I found: [link](https://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-import-data-from-Microsoft-Excel-to-a-Lotus-Notes-form-with-LotusScript). I'm sure that there are plenty of others. Many people would do this the other way, though, by writing VBA code that runs in Excel and calls the Lotus classes. A search here on StackOverflow for "send Lotus Notes email from Excel VBA" will definitely bring up some examples. One could also write VBScript code that runs standalone and uses both the Excel classes and the Notes classes, and you can undoubtedly find some examples of that, too.

Comment: Or you create a Mail Group in Notes...

Comment: @Richard Schwartz  - I've found many solutions with VB code and Excel macroes. But I prefer to run agents directly from Notes via action buttons. This way is more complicated and requires solid LotusScript knowledge which isn't my case. As you sad this way requires using NotesStream class and/or Open Statement. I've searched here and over Internet but didn't find any similar solution which imports recipients directly from excel file stored on local disk.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is decide whether you are reading your recipients from CSV or from an actual Excel worksheet file. Then you need to write a function called getRecipientsFromCSV or getRecipientsFromExcel. Then you need to find sample code to get you started. If you decide to read from CSV, then find some LotusScript samples that read from text files and try to figure out how to put similar code into your getRecipientsFromCSV function. If you have problems, then come back here to StackOverflow and ask a new specific question about the problems you are seeing with your new code.

Comment: And If you decide to read from Excel, then search for "access Excel from LotusScript". You will find some good examples. Figure out how that code is reading a cell value and write similar code in your getRecipientsFromExcel function.  If you have problems, then come back here to StackOverflow and ask a new specific question about the specific problems you are seeing with your new code.

Comment: Julian Robichaux wrote a useful CSV reader in LotusScript. See the example at http://www.nsftools.com/blog/blog-03-2006.htm#03-02-06. You should put his CSVReader class in a script library.